# Binary output Python optimization

Tags: python, optimization, binary, correlation

I wrote the following code. The objective of this code, is to generate a (binary) column with a given correlation with the first (binary) column.

However, it generates a column with the required correlation, but the generated column is not binary.

```
col1 =  np.random.randint(2,size=(10,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(col1)
corr_intra_semaine =0.61
corr_inter_semaine =0.57
start_1 =0
end_1=1

def f(corr, x, start_1, end_1):
    y = 0
    for k in range(start_1, end_1 + 1):
        y += abs(corr - pearsonr(df.iloc[:,k] , x)[0])    
    return y 


for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[:,i] = minimize(lambda x :  f(corr_intra_semaine, x, 0, i-1) 
                            , np.random.rand(len(df))).x

df
```

The result of this programe is the following

```
 0 -    0.000000
 0 -    0.579208
 0 -    0.968021
 1 -    0.938635
 0 -    0.639041
 0 -    0.503649
...
```

What I want is `df[:,i]` to be a binary vector. 
That is an output like that

```
 0 -    0
 0 -    1
 0 -    0
 1 -    1
 0 -    0
 0 -    1
...
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "binary". It would help the most if you showed what you want the result to look like.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the values in the result vector to be rounded to the nearest integer (0 or 1)?

Comment: @mkriger1 I edited the question by adding an example of what i want as an output. Is it clear now ? Thank you

Comment: It's a bit clearer, but I don't understand why `0.968021` and `0.639041` should become `0`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you for the reply,  I want that the solution of the optimization problem be either 0s or 1s, and not a float numbers.

Comment: What I meant was: Why should they become `0`, *and not `1`*?

Comment: Thank you @mkrieger1 . Either '0' or '1', but not a float.

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.rand(len(df))` floating point numbers from the interval `[0, 1)`. What about replacing it with a routine that randomly returns either 0 or 1?

```
numpy.random.randint(2, size=len(df))
```

In the minimization you cannot use floating point arithmetics afterwards, because that will once again yield floating point values. With the given setup, you cannot expect to get an exact value of the correlation for each input, but you could nevertheless flip values from 0 to 1 or vice-versa if that increases or decreases the correlation in the right way.

Another approach might be sampling in such a way that you directly get a good approximation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @piripiri, but this solution does not work. scince this parameter is only " Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,), where ‘n’ is the number of independent variables " and does not force the solution to be binary.